# how to separate region that does not contain another region

Tags: matlab

[image]

I have xC, yC, zC matrix there are only three color channels in the plot red, green, and blue. zC matrix has values either 1 for blue, 2 for green, or 3 for red.

I want to isolate only green which contains blue but not the green which is floating around it.

```
inb=zC==1;
xCb = xC(inb);   %isolate blue
yCb = yC(inb);

ing=zC==2;     %isolate green


xCg = xC(ing);
yCg = yC(ing);


inFg = inpolygon(xCb,yCb,xCg,yCg);  %tried inpolygon

in=zC==2;
zg = zC(in);  %This is not correct
zgV = zg(~inFg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/image.html) to use the functions [`imfill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) and [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), here's one solution:

```
blueMask = (zC == 1);   % Mask of blue regions
greenMask = (zC == 2);  % Mask of green regions

% Fill "holes" in the green mask, then get a list of pixel indices for each filled blob:
greenCC = regionprops(imfill(greenMask, 'holes'), 'PixelIdxList');

% Find which blobs have pixel indices that index any blue pixels:
blobIndex = cellfun(@(index) any(blueMask(index)), {greenCC.PixelIdxList});

% Collect pixel indices from these filled blobs:
greenIndex = vertcat(greenCC(blobIndex).PixelIdxList);

% Remove the indices of the filled holes:
greenIndex = greenIndex(greenMask(greenIndex));
```

This will give you a set of linear indices `greenIndex` for all pixels in the green regions that enclose blue regions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that assumes you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
% find green pixels with neighboring blue pixels. The linear indices will
% be stored in inds
zC_ = zeros(size(zC)+2);
zC_(2:(end-1),2:(end-1)) = zC;
neighboors = (zC==2) & ...
    ((zC_(1:(end-2),1:(end-2))==1) |...
    (zC_(1:(end-2),2:(end-1))==1) |...
    (zC_(1:(end-2),3:end)==1) |...
    (zC_(2:(end-1),1:(end-2))==1) |...
    (zC_(2:(end-1),3:end)==1) |...
    (zC_(3:end,1:(end-2))==1) |...
    (zC_(3:end,2:(end-1))==1) |...
    (zC_(3:end,3:end)==1));
inds = find(neighboors);

% find all connected regions of green pixels which are in the vector inds.
% result will be stored in inds2.
conn = bwlabeln(zC==2);
inds2 = ismember(conn(:),unique(conn(inds)));

% create an output image with 0's anywhere beside the regions you need are
% interested in
out = zeros(size(zC));
out(inds2) = 1;
```